# If I deliberately kill someone in self-defence, but my prior unlawful actions provoked the fight, is that involuntary act manslaughter?

Tags: united-kingdom, manslaughter

Suppose I steal from someone whom I know to be a violent criminal, and the next day they hunt me down and try to kill me in revenge, and I defend myself by stabbing them to death. Suppose further that the jury is convinced that this was a reasonable use of force in self-defence, and that I am therefore not guilty of murder.

What about manslaughter? Assuming the sequence of events that in fact unfolded is deemed by the jury to have been a foreseeable potential consequence of the initial theft, am I guilty of [unlawful act manslaughter](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/homicide-murder-manslaughter-infanticide-and-causing-or-allowing-death-or-serious)?

On the one hand, my theft from the victim in the first place was a criminal act which predictably created risk of physical harm and did in fact (albeit indirectly) cause the victim's death, which meets the definition of unlawful act manslaughter.

On the other hand:

- Unlawful act manslaughter is generally classed as a form of *involuntary* manslaughter, so it's strange to apply it to a case where in the end I deliberately stabbed the victim to death.
- Also, the defence of self-defence applies to manslaughter, so if the jury was convinced I had a valid self-defence argument with regards to the murder, shouldn't it get me off the manslaughter too?
- Finally, there is an argument to be made that the victim attacking me was a *novus actus interveniens* that breaks the chain of causation from the theft to the death.

But on the first hand again:

- The killing kind of *is* involuntary in this framing; the theft led, against my will, to circumstances in which I had to kill the victim.
- And if we're framing the death in that way, it's no clear that the defence of self-defence applies, since [it is only](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/self-defence-and-prevention-crime) *"available as a defence to crimes committed by use of force"*. In a sense, I didn't commit the manslaughter here by use of force; I committed it by carrying out the initial theft, which set in motion the consequences that led to the victim's death.
- And intervening acts by third parties don't *automatically* break the chain of causation; there's nuanced case law about when they do or don't.

(I suspect scenarios broadly similar to this happen fairly often in real life, and that there's a good chance there's case law out there that speaks to *precisely* the question I'm asking. Indeed I've seen multiple stories in the media in the past involving self-defence stabbings where it appears the stabber may have been guilty of some kind criminal act that started the fight, and they ultimately got convicted of manslaughter but not murder. I'm trying to figure out whether that is indeed a possible explanation for the convictions, or whether something else is going on in all these cases.)

Comment: In this scenario are you intentionally conspiring to have them retaliate against you in order to have "justification" to use lethal force?

Comment: @jesse_b Let's assume not. (I imagine that if I had been, the self-defence defence would fail against the murder charge, anyway, though the case law I thought I'd read on that point isn't as crystal clear as I remembered and only addresses provocation occurring in the immediate context of the incident, not well prior to it.)

Comment: Yes I figured as much but it suppose I read a little to far into "whom I know to be a violent criminal" as potential anticipation of retaliation.

Comment: @jesse_b I included the "whom I know to be a violent criminal" because one of the requisites for unlawful act manslaughter is that physical harm must be a foreseeable risk of the unlawful act (although I'm not clear on the exact standard of how severe the risk must be and [noticed recently that the case law is confusingly contradictory](https://twitter.com/XplodingCabbage/status/1631634252092538883)) and I figured if the person provoked wasn't known to be a violent criminal some commenters would protest that a murderous reaction to the provocation wasn't foreseeable.

Comment: I imagine it all depends a lot on a lot of things but vigilantly justice is also a crime for a reason.  No matter the circumstances it's probably pretty hard to get away with a self defense killing in the UK but in the US you would probably have pretty good odds.

Answer (score 1):

### You answered the question in your first paragraph

> Suppose further that the jury is convinced that this was a reasonable use of force in self-defence …

Whether the killing was in self-defence *in the circumstances* is a matter of fact for the jury to decide. They decided it was self-defence, therefore, you are not guilty.

Whether the evidence of your theft would be a matter placed before the jury is a question of law for the judge to decide - I can see some heated arguments around this. The defence would certainly claim that it should be excluded on the basis of irrelevance; the prosecution is going to argue the other way. Each will make their submissions and the judge will decide whether it’s admissible or not.

Either way, the jury, considering all the matters placed before them, is the arbiter on self-defence or any other lawful justification for the killing.

Comment: -1 because I outlined in the question why I thought the defence of self-defence might not apply here, and this answer doesn't address the argument. Unlawful act manslaughter is not inherently a crime involving use of *force* (and therefore not a crime to which the the defence of self-defence is inherently applicable) and the specific unlawful act (theft) that caused the victim's death didn't involve force either. The force only came into play later, as a *consequence* of the unlawful act that is meant to be the actual culpable action in the unlawful act manslaughter theory.

Comment: If it helps clarify the point: consider also the scenario where the victim I steal from wrongly believes my twin brother to have been the thief and seeks to take revenge on my twin brother, who kills him in justified self-defence. Then I would be guilty of unlawful act manslaughter under essentially the same theory, but would clearly not be able to claim self-defence. Can it really be that, because of the coincidence that ***I*** am the person who ends up wielding the knife in self-defence, I also get let off the hook for my theft having caused the death? That seems arbitrary, if it is true!

Comment: @MarkAmery It would be beyond absurdity to consider another person’s act of revenge as a “predictable consequence”.

Comment: @Sneftel That seems like a separate criticism of the question orthogonal to anything in this answer or comment thread. (I also don't see why you think it's true. It is often entirely possible to see there is a risk that someone will retaliate against a provocation, and we *do* in fact teach and expect people to foresee and be cautious of such risks in all sorts of contexts.)

Answer (score 1):

In the US, the jury has great power to decide the facts. Even actual [innocence isn't a legal defense](https://www.thedailybeast.com/the-supreme-court-just-said-in-in-shinn-v-ramirez-that-evidence-of-innocence-is-not-enough) if the jury rules you guilty. Yes, [it's that bad](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97639/if-a-former-witness-was-found-guilty-of-a-crime-or-deemed-otherwise-unreliable). But this cuts both ways: the jury can also declare the defendant not guilty, even if that's not legally correct.

From your description, *unless the whole sequence was planned in advance*, defending yourself in an altercation on another day can qualify as self-defense. Your the crime of theft is then be a separate offense, which can be charged and tried separately from the killing.

There is a principle of [chain of causation](https://www.bljsolicitors.co.uk/blog/causation-in-criminal-law-explained/) when it applies to manslaughter or (more rarely) murder by indirect means. Putting a brick on the gas to launch a car into a crowd is murder, since no one else needs to commit a guilty act for deaths to occur.

If you were caught in the act of stealing, and the victim attacked you to defend their property, you could both be guilty. Killing the victim would be considered felony murder, as this killing resulted directly from your criminal act. If the theft's victim killed you, that would likely be manslaughter, since defense of property alone (without any perceived threat to their life or health) doesn't justify lethal force.

Someone deciding to take revenge on you, after your crime has been completed, breaks the chain of causation. It's their decision to decide how to respond, making *them* the responsible guilty actor in the chain of causation. Their crime is then murder or attempted murder.

Theft with the specific purpose of provoking an altercation with another would, however, break the defense's argument of self-defense. That's prima facie first degree murder: creating, with premeditation, a chain of events that predictably leads to another's death. The actual murder is committed when you stab them, since this altercation has been intended and premeditated.

TL;DR: It can go both ways, depending on whether you intended the victim's death.

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Comment: As with the answer about German law, I question the relevance of this, but if we *are* going to talk about the US then I believe some concepts present in many US jurisdictions and roughly analogous to the UK's "unlawful act manslaughter" are "felony murder" and "constructive manslaughter" (for causing death via a felony or a misdemeanour, respectively) and this answer doesn't mention them at all. The point about the chain of causation is pertinent but you don't back up your interpretation that any guilty act by another party breaks it with case law so I don't know if it's true.

Comment: (Indeed I'm pretty sure that interpretation of how the chain of causation works is *not* true in the UK since, per sources discussing the principle, people here who have caused someone to be injured and hospitalised have been held responsible for additional injuries to the victim by medical malpractice while in hospital, on the grounds that they wouldn't've been in hospital and exposed to that risk at all but for the initial injury. This doesn't seem consistent with the logic here. But perhaps the US is different.)

Comment: @MarkAmery The rules of law.SE [encourage answers from other jurisdictions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/when-is-a-jurisdiction-tag-required-in-a-question). The short version is: harm caused in treating the injury stems from the initial crime of assault and battery. A decision to take revenge is a separate crime. But I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

There are three potential crimes you might commit if you stab a person on purpose and they then die. These are *schwere Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge* (aggrevated assault leading to death), *Totschlag* (manslaughter) and *Mord* (murder). The difference between the former and the latter two is whether you intended the stabbed person to die or whether that just happened.

In order to claim self defense when stabbing someone, your intended damage musn't exceed incapaciting the opponent. This might lead to their death, but you should be thinking "I want this guy to stop attacking me", not "I want this guy dead".

Self defence might also be unavailable as legal defence if you caused the situation. If you are caught stealing something and this leads to a fight with the owner, a self-defense claim would probably be denied on these grounds. (It's a different situation if someone you wronged in the past tracks you down to enact revenge.) If you-stabbing-him acts would have counted as self-defense if not for your responsibility for the situation, the natural charge would be  *schwere Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge*.

Comment: I realise that the established norm on LSE is that answers relating to different jurisdictions are acceptable, but I don't really see the point of answering a question specifically about the concept of "unlawful act manslaughter" in the UK by talking about another jurisdiction and *not even noting whether anything analogous to the concept of "unlawful act manslaughter" exists in that jurisdiction*, let alone analysing how that analogous offence would apply to the question.

Comment: As for *schwere Körperverletzung mit Todesfolge*... I don't speak German and haven't read the laws in question, but I don't see how a *theft* that leads an altercation in which self-defence leads to death could ever constitute an "*aggravated assault* leading to death". The *theft* is not an assault, and the stabbing is presumably not either if it's self-defence (unless there are different standards of self-defence for aggravated assault versus murder? But you don't say so...)

Comment: @MarkAmery it's a thing of german self defense law: you can not gain self defense in a situation if you initiated the situation. If the thief attacks the guard, there is no self defense but at least "aggravated assault with deadly outcome", or a homicide.

Comment: @trish But there must surely be some cut-off point beyond which you can't be said to have initiated the situation. The OP's scenario is that the theft victim returned *the next day* to kill the thief; it didn't happen immediately after the theft. What if it was a week, a year, 10 years, etc.? Could I be said to have initiated the situation if I look at someone the wrong way and they decide to kill me a day later? I'd be surprised if German law didn't have some rule for determining what counts as initiation.

Comment: @JBentley only by *properly retreating*.

Comment: @Trish Are you suggesting that a thief who is hunted down the next day didn't properly retreat? I'm just having a hard time reconciling your example (thief attacks the guard) with the OP's scenario in which the theft and the attack are separated by a whole day

Comment: @JBentley no, I am not. I am saying that there is a line that is well established when one regains self defense.